# Based on time range,how to grep entire thread log from application log in python

Tags: python

Based on time range, how to grep entire thread trace from application log in python.

How to get entire thread lines from application log in python. Time window will be user parameters.

Sample log:

```
2019-04-05 thread1:File created with reference1
2019-04-05 thread1: splitted successful 2019-04-05 thread1: archival moved. 
2019-04-05 thread2: file created with reference 2.
```

Comment: Post the sample of the application log

Comment: 2019-04-05 thread1:File created with reference1                 2019-04-05 thread1: splitted successful                          2019-04-05 thread1: archival moved.                                  2019-04-05 thread2: file created with reference 2.                .......                In this case,we need grep the first 3 lines (thread1) based user parameter 'reference1' .

Comment: You can update that in the question

Comment: Sample log:                                                                      2019-04-05 thread1:File created with reference1 2019-04-05 thread1: splitted successful 2019-04-05 thread1: archival moved. 2019-04-05 thread2: file created with reference 2. ....... In this case,we need grep the first 3 lines (thread1) based user parameter 'reference1

Comment: No timestamp apart from the date ?

Comment: The date included minutes and seconds, milliseconds.